# This is a many to many relationship model for question

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this code. The third table shows an error message. There is no error in the first and second table. The error message is below. Please help me to find out the cause of the error.

**Error message:**

```
mysql> create table Registation(
-> cid int,
-> sid int,
-> reg Date date,
-> reg_fee int not null default 2000,
-> constraint primary key (sid,cid),
-> constraint foreign key(sid) references student(sid)
-> on delete cascade on update cascade,
-> constraint foreign key(cid) references course(cid)
-> on delete cascade on update cascade );
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'date,
>   reg_fee int not null default 2000,
>   constraint primary key (sid,cid),
>   const' at line 4

***My SQL Table code:***

```
create table student(
sid int auto_increment,
name varchar(100)not null,
address varchar(100)not null,
constraint primary key(sid),
constraint name_address unique(name,address) );

create table course(
cid int auto_increment,
title varchar(100)not null,
duration varchar(10)not null,
constraint primary key(cid) );

create table Registation(
cid int,
sid int,
reg Date date,
reg_fee int not null default 2000,
constraint primary key (sid,cid),
constraint foreign key(sid) references student(sid)
on delete cascade on update cascade,
constraint foreign key(cid) references course(cid)
on delete cascade on update cascade );
```

Comment: 'Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:

ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)

Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF' you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html and fix reg date

Comment: Oh Thank You Anirban166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your registration table is incorrect.

```
create table Registation(
cid int,
sid int,
reg Date date,/* line 1
reg_fee int not null default 2000,
constraint primary key (sid,cid),
constraint foreign key(sid) references student(sid)
on delete cascade on update cascade,
constraint foreign key(cid) references course(cid)
on delete cascade on update cascade );
```

Line 1 is modify to reg  date,

Correct code is,

```
create table Registation(
cid int,
sid int,
Date date,/* line 1
reg_fee int not null default 2000,
constraint primary key (sid,cid),
constraint foreign key(sid) references student(sid)
on delete cascade on update cascade,
constraint foreign key(cid) references course(cid)
on delete cascade on update cascade );
```

or

```
create table Registation(
cid int,
sid int,
reg_Date date,/* line 1
reg_fee int not null default 2000,
constraint primary key (sid,cid),
constraint foreign key(sid) references student(sid)
on delete cascade on update cascade,
constraint foreign key(cid) references course(cid)
on delete cascade on update cascade );
```

Comment: Thank You Shashini Probodha 